# Assign values to a pandas dataframe column filtered by index and column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a DateTime index and two columns called `'text'` and `'labels'`. I want to assign the value of `labels which have value =2` and lie within a DateTime index range with `value =50`

I tried using,

```
df[df['labels']==2]['2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00':'2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00']['labels']=50
```

I am able to view the DataFrame filtered by DataTime index (rows) and columns but not able to assign it

Also tried

```
df.loc[df['2017-03-13 00:00:00':'2017-03-23 00:00:00'], df['labels']==2]=50
```

but it threw an error

df looks like

```
created                                text                      labels
2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00   break john cena eyelash grow            4
2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00   eyelash tooooo much sweeti definit      2
2017-02-01 05:14:57+00:00   come eyelash                            2
```

created is the DateTime index and 'text' and 'labels' are the columns of the DataFrame

```
df[df['labels']==2]['2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00':'2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00']['labels']
```

filters the DataFrame but doesn't assign it if we set it equal to a value

On assigning the DataFrame for created between `'2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00':'2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00'`  and `labels =2` for labels=50 I expect the result to be like this

```
created                                text                      labels
2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00   break john cena eyelash grow            4
2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00   eyelash tooooo much sweeti definit      50
2017-02-01 05:14:57+00:00   come eyelash                            2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `get_level_values`

```
s=df.index.get_level_values(0)
m=(s>'2017-02-01 05:03:25+00:00') & (s<='2017-02-01 05:05:55+00:00')
df.loc[m&(df.labels==2),'lable']=50
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!  So we should give both the condition is given as row filters